# Access second level child in Json based on a variable

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm currently working on a configuration service in my Angular 2 application, my current concern is about the utilization of eval in my code to retrieve a value in my configuration.

Here's a sample of my configuration file:

```
{
  "application": {
    "environment": "dev",
    "displayMenu": false
  },

  "error": {
    "title": "Title Error",
    "message": "Error message"
  }
}
```

I'm retrieving this JSON with a simple HTTP request, but now I would like to access an element with my get method defined like this:

```
get(key: any) {
    return (eval("this._config." + key));
}
```

As you can see, there is an eval in my code that I would like to avoid. I'm forced to use eval to allow the developer to do .get('application.environment') and actually I don't find any others an easy possibility.

The only other way that I could see is to split the key on a "." and retrieve the right element in my JSON like it was a simple array. But with this solution, I would be stuck to one depth only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array of your object keys you wish to view, then reduce that array returning the key of the object. If you wish to have a string as the object accessors you can easily use `string.split('.')` to create the array you can reduce.

```js
const data = {
  "application": {
    "environment": "dev",
    "displayMenu": false
  },
  "error": {
    "title": "Title Error",
    "message": "Error message",
    "deeper": {
      "evenDeeper": "You can get to any level"
    }
  }
}

const path = (keys, obj) => {
  return keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
    return typeof obj !== 'undefined' 
      ? obj[key]
      : void 0
  }, obj)
}

console.log(
  path(['application', 'environment'], data)
)
console.log(
  path('error.message'.split('.'), data) // move the split inside the path function
)
console.log(
  path(['error', 'deeper', 'evenDeeper'], data)
)
console.log(
  path(['error', 'fail', 'damn'], data) // fail safe
)
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks to you, edited it a bit to match my code and it's perfectly fine. Feel way better than using a dirty eval :D

Comment: if you do use eval, make sure you use `const evil = eval` as the very first line of your code.